Spring boot redis cache integration in filter
I have a strange issue here. I have a filter which has two filter methods one with ContainerRequestContext as param and other with both ContainerRequestContext and ContainerResponseContext as mentioned below. When there is a cache hit I am aborting the ContainerRequestContext with 200 http response. But in Cache hit scenario its generating a http status as 201 which we want to avoid. I tried to use responseContext.setStatus(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()); in the response filter still I am getting 201 as final response.Any help will be appreciated.
@Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
                cacheKey = cacheservice.makekey(requestContext);
                packetData = cacheservice.getValue(cacheKey);
            if (packetData != null) {
                requestContext.abortWith(
                        Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                                .entity(packetData)
                                .build()
                );
            }
    }


@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
               packetData = cacheservice.getValue(cacheKey);
                if (packetData != null) {
                    setResponseContextAttributes(String.valueOf(100),responseContext,”Cache hit”);
           responseContext.setStatus(Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode());
                } else {
            cacheKey = cacheservice.makekey(requestContext);
                    packetData = (Object) responseContext.getEntity();
                    cacheservice.setValue(cacheKey, packetData, 100);
                    setResponseContextAttributes(String.valueOf(100),responseContext,”Cache miss”);
        }
}


This seems to be show stopper issue due to change of the success code. any help will be appreciated
